# Pushing to another ViewController from UIScrollview UIView SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I've a scrollview that display information in a Carousel manner, what I want to do now is add click event on each and every View in the carousel, I was able to do that by adding **UITapGestureRecongnizer*** whenever it pushes, it Logs an error ***nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar** out and also it displays the wrong information
Below is my code for loading the Carousel View and adding Click event, and also the data on the Carousel are gotten from a **jSON** and stored with **NSObject** in a **NSMutableArray*...

```
 -(void)updateUI:(NSMutableArray *)array {

CGFloat contentOffset = 0.0f;

for (NSString *dis in carouselArray) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(contentOffset, 0.0f, responseScroll.frame.size.width, responseScroll.frame.size.height);

    UIView *views = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    views.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    //imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *imageMove = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moreViewMove)];
    imageMove.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    NSString *urls = [dis valueForKey:@"imageURL"];
    if ([urls  isEqual: @""]) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
    } else {
        [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urls]];
    }

    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 132, 152, 21)];
    name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:13];
    name.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    name.text = [dis valueForKey:@"name"];
    UILabel *address = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 149, 194, 21)];
    address.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:12];
    address.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    address.text = [dis valueForKey:@"address"];
    UILabel *km = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(278, 133, 42, 21)];
    km.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:11];
    CLLocation *current = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *itemLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dis valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dis valueForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]];
    CLLocationDistance itemDist = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:current]/1000;
    //NSLog(@"Distance: %f", itemDist);
    km.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2fkm", itemDist];
    views.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [views addGestureRecognizer:imageMove];
    _starRating = [[EDStarRating alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(234, 149, 78, 16)];
    _starRating.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] ;
    _starRating.starHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"starhighlighted.png"];
    _starRating.maxRating = 5.0;
    _starRating.delegate = self;
    _starRating.horizontalMargin = 0;
    _starRating.editable=NO;
    _starRating.rating= [[dis valueForKey:@"rating"] floatValue];
    _starRating.displayMode=EDStarRatingDisplayHalf;
    [views addSubview:imageView];
    [views addSubview:name];
    [views addSubview:address];
    [views addSubview:km];
    [views addSubview:_starRating];
    [responseScroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [responseScroll addSubview:views];

    [responseScroll addGestureRecognizer:imageMove];

    contentOffset += views.frame.size.width;
    responseScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentOffset, views.frame.size.height);
}

}
```

And the code for handling View Click Events is below, I know I'm doing it wrong but I can't figure out what to do here.

```
-(void)moreViewMove {


for (NSString *dat in carouselArray) {
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"u_id.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dico = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSString *place_id = [dat valueForKey:@"place_id"];
    NSString *place_reference = [dat valueForKey:@"place_reference"];

    CLLocation *current = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:startLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:startLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *itemLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dat valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue] longitude:[[dat valueForKey:@"lon"] floatValue]];
    CLLocationDistance itemDist = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:current]/1000;

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSString *u_id = [[device identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    if ([dico objectForKey:@"u_id"]) {
        moreView *more = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreView"];
        more.names = [dat valueForKey:@"name"];
        more.currentLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
        more.currentLon = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
        more.destinationLon = [dat valueForKey:@"lon"];
        more.destinationLat = [dat valueForKey:@"lat"];
        more.addressL = [dat valueForKey:@"address"];
        more.kilo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2fkm", itemDist];
        more.dataURL = @{@"type": @"details",@"u_id":[dico objectForKey:@"u_id"], @"place_id": place_id, @"place_reference": place_reference, @"device":@"server"};
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:more animated:YES];
    } 
}

}
```

Please, any help would be Appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most unusual part of the code is the loop in `moreViewMove`.  It looks like it will allocate and push up to N view controllers, where N is the number of elements in `carouselArray`.

The general pattern for this sort of thing is to have a loop that creates the views based on the model, a gesture recognizer to get the taps, and means to map the tap back to the model.  Then the tap handler just looks up a single model item and performs navigation.

The loop in `updateUI:` creates the subviews and gesture recognizers.  A common means of mapping the views back to the model is with the view's `tag` property.  In your updateUI, you would do something like this:

```
UIView *views = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
views.tag = [carouselArray indexOfObject:dis];

// ...
// change the gesture recognizer selector to take a parameter
// notice the colon on the selector moreViewMove:
UITapGestureRecognizer *imageMove = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moreViewMove:)];
```

Now in moreViewMove:, you can find out which index was tapped because the gesture recognizer will be sent as a param...

```
- (void)moreViewMove:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    // don't put a loop in here.
    // probably don't build a dictionary in here that doesn't depend on which item was tapped

    UIView *theViewThatWasTapped = gr.view;
    NSInteger tag = theViewThatWasTapped.tag;

    // now, we can know what part of our model was tapped
    NSString *dis = carouselArray[tag];

    // check how you're doing with an NSLog
    NSLog(@"user tapped view with tag %ld model is %@", tag, dis);

    // your job now is to allocate a single view controller,
    // configure it with your model (dis) and push it
```

Do as little work as you can to configure the new vc.  Any init stuff that's invariant with respect to what part of the model was selected should be moved elsewhere, hopefully into that new view controller's initialization.

Comment: Come on, you just made my day Hommie, loooooolllllll I was actually told the same thing by a friend at work today, but couldn't understand him very well. Thanks a bunch man, thank You very much, but the problem now is that it selects only the first view in the scroll, if I click on the next view it gives me information of the first one

Comment: Glad you're making progress.  In the moreViewMove: method, can you add the logging I suggest in the edit to the moreViewMove method above.

Comment: It's always selecting **Tag 0**

Comment: So next, NSLog the tag when you set it in updateUI.  You can also log the gesture recognizer (with %@ or %p) and compare it to the one sent in moveViewMove:

Comment: Yep, it tagged it well. It is tagging it very well accurately, there are just four dictionaries in the array now and it's giving each a tag Number

Comment: So you create 4 views, give each a unique tag, and give each a unique gr.  Then, no matter which gr you tap, the value of gr.view.tag is the same, all == 0?  Also, did you say dictionaries?  We have 'dis' declared as a string.

Comment: Lemme tell you how it's structured A jSON response that has an array of 4 dictionaries, I used an NSObject to extract it creating four string in the NSObject class, and using the string to save it in a Mutable array which is CarouselArray, and then accessing and displaying in the for loop in the **UpdateUI:** function checking for every string in each dictionary and displaying it. Why I'm doing it that way is cause the Results coming in might increase soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54079/discussion-between-danh-and-sandspy).